# Convergence of total quadratic variation to predictable quadratic variation for continuous martingales: proof clarification.

Tags: martingales, absolute-continuity, quadratic-variation, local-martingales

Suppose that $X\in\mathcal{M}^2_c$ is a continuous square-integrable martingale. By the Doob-Meyer decomposition there exists an increasing predictable process $\left<X\right>_t$ such that $X_t^2-\left<X\right>_t$ is a martingale. Besides the fact that $X$ is continuous implies that $\left<X\right>$ is also continuous.
For $X\in\mathcal{M}^2_c$ many authors deliver the popular result
$$
p-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(X_{t_{k}}-X_{t_{k-1}}\right)^2 = \left<X\right>_t
$$
with $0=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n=t$ a partition of $[0,t]$. In proving this, the approach is the following. First it is assumed that, almost surely, $|X|\leq K$. Then a localization argument is used for the generic case. My problem is: if $X$ is a.s. continuous on the compact set $[0,t]$ shouldnt be automatic that, a.s.,  $|X|\leq K$ ?

Comment: No. If $X$ is a.s. continuous on the compact set $[0,t]$ this means that for a.e. $\omega$ there is a $K(\omega)$ and so on and so forth. To do the localization argument one needs a $K$ that works for almost every $\omega$. Please ask one question at a time and do justice to [Joseph L. Doob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_L._Doob) by spelling his name correctly.

Comment: thanks, sorry for the typo, edited accordingly.